# Connect onClick listener to Dojo widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following function:

```javascript
function setAccounts(data){
    var node = dijit.byId("res");
    dojo.empty("res");
    for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
        var itemWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
            id: data[i].id,
            rightText: "€ "+data[i].amount,
            moveTo: "transactions",
            label: data[i].name
        });
        node.addChild(itemWidget);
        dojo.connect(itemWidget, "onclick", getTransactions(data[i].id));
    }
}
```

At page loading it doesn't connect the onClick event of the new itemWidget to the function getTransactions but it simply runs that function. Where is the error ?

The data is json obtained via ajax and I've already checked that there's no error there on in json reading/parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo's 'connect' method expects an HTMLElement as the first argument. However, the dojo widgets you create are actually very specialized JavaScript objects - though they tend to make their HTMLElement available under the `.domNode` property.

Actually, the easiest solution I know of would be to use the available onClick attribute inside ListItem.

```
var itemWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
        id: data[i].id,
        rightText: "€ "+data[i].amount,
        moveTo: "transactions",
        label: data[i].name,
        onClick: dojo.hitch(this, 'getTransactions', data[I].id)
    });
```

If you do end up `connect`-ing other events to a widget, I'd recommend writing it as `itemWidget.connect(targetNode, etc` - to my knowledge, that will remove event listeners if/when the widget itself is destroyed.

Comment: If `getTransactions` isn't a member function of this object, you could use [`dojo.partial`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/partial.html): `dojo.partial(getTransactions, data[i].id)`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your function runs once immediately is because you're calling it here:

```
dojo.connect(itemWidget, "onclick", getTransactions(data[i].id));
```

What you should be doing is passing a function that *will be called later* when the element is clicked. You can do this with [`dojo.partial`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/partial.html), which creates a function that will be called with specific arguments when invoked. You can also explicitly pass the widget's DOM node, which is something that @Katana314 alluded to. You can do this if you want to keep your current code layout in case modifying the creation of your items isn't something you can easily do at this point.

```
dojo.connect(itemWidget.domNode, "onclick", dojo.partial(getTransactions, data[i].id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this,

```
function setAccounts(data){
    var node = dijit.byId("res");
    dojo.empty("res");
    for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
        var itemWidget = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
            id: data[i].id,
            rightText: "€ "+data[i].amount,
            onclick:getTransactions,
            moveTo: "transactions",
            label: data[i].name
        });
        node.addChild(itemWidget);

    }
}

var getTransactions=function(){
//your code.
}
```